# Territory Management: Formula to access Parent Territory from Opportunity

Tags: territory

We're using Territory Management. We want to have the name of the Parent Territory available on the Opportunity.

Parent Territory is a standard field on the Territory sObject. However, it does not appear to be available in the "insert" feature of the formula creator.

I've attempted to access it from a formula on Opportunity and I attempted to access it from a custom formula from the Territory Object itself.

Is there a way to get the Parent territory exposed via a formula? Do I have to resort to a Trigger?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Abandoned

Comment: I'm voting to leave this question open because I believe that there was a better answer to Brian's question that hadn't been posted yet.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one solution:

1. Add a small VF page to your standard Opportunity layout
2. Have the VF page use a VF controller
3. VF controller can traverse the territory-parent territory relationship using SOQL. You also might also be able to do this with merge fields and skip the controller in #2 altogether - I didn't test this.

Advantages:

1. You can extend and display more territory data in the mini VF component on the Opportunity detail page
2. As territory hierarchy changes, Opportunity detail page, when refreshed, reflects new hierarchy

Disadvantages:

1. You can't report on the field as it is generated by VF only. Same with List Views

The trigger solution is not the right (or complete) answer as it won't be sensitive to the territory hierarchy changing. Instead, you'll need to have a scheduled job that updates the Opportunity reflecting the current hierarchy every `<you decide how often .. daily, hourly>`.

Answer (score -1):

I also wasn't able to find the parent territory name under the "input" select screen, but I was able to get it by typing the formula directly:

```
Territory2.ParentTerritory2.Name
```

---

This answer has been getting more attention recently, and I took another look at it again today, and it looks like it is still valid.

[image]

[image]

[image]